# Please reopen this question that was improved by the community

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

A couple years ago, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2835559/1394393) was [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381492/1394393). As a result, substantial improvements were made to its content, and the dominant community opinion seems to be that it's now good enough to leave open. It's a common enough problem that can be a little hard to diagnose (especially for beginners and in some more complex cases), meaning the question provides quite a lot of value for developers who encounter similar cases.

Unfortunately, it has since been closed. Please help reopen it. I would like to, but I'm blocked from casting a reopen vote due to having previously done so.

It may also be worth adding a moderator note, or at least wiping the comments and leaving some authoritative commentary referencing the previous Meta question. Particularly since it seems to have gone through a couple of close/reopen cycles already.

Comment: Whilst I want to argue that it’s a pretty useless question, the number of upvotes/net score says otherwise. That said, I’m unsure why it needs to be reopened given there’s already a good answer.

Comment: The upvotes could just as well be from people looking for a copy-pastable snippet to parse json. Seeing as the OP's code isn't the problem...

Comment: This is still a horrible question - at best, it is a duplicate of a hypothetical "What is valid JSON?" (do we have one, btw, maybe this one should be reclosed against it?) and has nothing to do with Python. At worst, it is a "no repro or typo" situation because the OP seems to have no idea what vlid JSON is (at the time of asking, at least). The sad fact that it, apparently, "helped" 1500+ users is purely coincidental, and a canonical on `JSONDecodeError` (btw, do we have one?) would be *way* more helpful. Not to mention all the "not-technically-an-naa" answers but talk about how to read JSON.

Comment: I also don’t agree that the earlier meta question concluded that question should stay open. The answers argue that it’s of value to the site, but don’t provide an argument on why it shouldn’t be closed.

Comment: Now... I have to follow up on my comment above. I took a look at the revision history of the question, and am now inclined to think that it's actually *us* who made it a "no repro/typo" question in the first place. The OP's original (albeit rather basic) question *wasn't* about `JSONDecodeError` at all and was asking about extraction of individual values from the parsed JSON (note the "it only print all the text" implying (in tandem with the code) that the parsing happens *correctly*, which now lead me to think that the lack of curly brackets around key-value pairs was just a copy-paste [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] error on the OPs part. At some point in time (revs [13](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2835559/13)-14 specifically), the question was made *specifically* about the parsing error which also invalidated a bunch of answers that do not address the issue the OP did not ask about at all (but would be considered valid given the state of the question before the edits). It now makes more sense that they exist.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The typo that makes it invalid JSON already exists in the first revision.

Comment: Definitely, @MarkRotteveel - however, as I outlined in my alternative proposal on what can be possibly done with the Q&A, after digging further, I came to the conclusion that despite the typo being present from rev 1 indeed, the question wasn't really about the typo itself but rather about reading and parsing JSON files - and that it is also why it accumulated so many upvotes. This also explains why most of the answers ignore the now blatantly obvious typo.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine We don't know whether or not it was, because the original revision was an unclear question. It should have been closed from the start, which unfortunately didn't happen at that time.

Comment: It was poorly written, but I think there is a pretty unambiguous interpretation for the original intent - evidenced by the original sequence of events. I added another answer detailing this.

Comment: The question has now been closed and locked. *"This question is not reproducible or was caused by typos. It is not currently accepting answers."* and *"This question and its answers are locked because the question is off-topic but has historical significance. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions."* respectively.

Comment: Re *"added another answer"*: To this meta question.

Answer (score 30):

No man, that's just someone parsing invalid JSON...

That's a typo question! The answer is literally *"Your code is fine, fix your JSON"*.

We get questions like this ***all the time***, and seeing as it's *not* the top result when searching Google for *"python parse json stack overflow"*, I don't see it as a particularly useful signpost, either.

The question doesn't require any more answers, so what reason would there be for this question to *need* to be re-opened? Last time it was closed, a mod closed it...

It currently has **9** deleted answers, and (at least) one answer that doesn't even answer the question.

(I'm also a little disappointed that this meta question has been acted upon, before *any* discussion took place)

Comment: Re the parenthetical: I wonder why you're disappointed by close/reopen votes being cast before any discussion took place? Even disregarding the fact that there's already an extensive discussion on meta about the linked question in its current state, users are welcome to take actions on posts linked from meta as soon as they want, aren't they? If a discussion is needed first, what counts as a discussion? A certain number of comments, a certain number of answers, answers saying opposite things, or something else?

Comment: I always thought it was an unwritten rule not to act on questions that were being discussed on Meta, while there wasn't a consensus yet... But I might be wrong there, @cigien

Comment: No, I wouldn't really consider that a rule. One reason is, it's not always clear when, or even if, there's a consensus reached, which would make it difficult to take any action. Also, even if there is a consensus, users are free to vote in a manner opposite to that (barring explicit instructions from a mod, and such), so waiting on a consensus wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: The discussion literally happened years ago. Additionally, the original JSON was generated by code the OP didn't write, meaning it was not in fact a typo.

Comment: Incorrectly generated JSON still qualifies as a typo… That discussion years ago never really came to a clear conclusion. It never really argued that it shouldn’t be closed.

Comment: @Cerbrus A staff member literally talked about saving useful content from it. If that doesn't qualify as an argument against closure, then nothing does. Closure means the question has a problem that only the author can fix (or not even them) and that renders the question mostly useless; barring a historical lock situation, it is designed to be an opportunity to fix the question prior to deletion. The conclusion of the discussion was clearly that it's good enough and useful, despite not being fantastic.

Comment: Closure is not deletion. Closed questions like this, with a lot of upvotes, don't get deleted automatically, and hardly ever get deleted by a moderator. A JSON typo doesn't need more answers, I mean, just look at the load of deleted answers on there already.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative proposal to what to do with this Q&A that bypasses the admittedly divisive discussion on whether it should be reopened, it can be:

- merged with the [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file) canonical;
- the answers can be cleaned of mentions of malformed JSON;

The problem with the Q&A under discussion is that, originally, it *was not* about the malformed JSON at all (substantiated by the use of `json.loads` that raises the `JSONDecodeError`, of which there originally was no mention, and the OP's claim that their script "prints all of the json text"), and was likely commonly landed on by users in search of a solution to a common problem of reading and parsing files containing JSON strings.

An good indicator that this was the case is the [voting history](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1612207#graph) on the post, where the bulk of the score was accumulated *before* the edits were made:

[image: graph of upvotes on the question grouped by year with a steady increase up to 2019 and a sharp decline afterwards]

The edits that made the Q&A explicitly about the malformed JSON happened in early 2019 (specifically, [revision 13](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2835559/13)) and put the Q&A in a scizophrenic state: most of the answers on it started to look like they are glossing over the obviously invalid JSON.

While the edits did, indeed, improve the overall quality of the post, they also seem to be the source for the close / reopen shenanigans that ensued (note the distinct cutoff when the close / reopen cycles start in the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2835559/timeline) — right after the edits) as they *did* made the post seem to be "not reproducible or caused by a typo".

In its original state, though, the question and the answers significantly (significantly might be an understatement — they seem to cover the same ground) overlap with another prominent Q&A: [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file) This suggests that, to cut this Gordian knot, they can be merged to form a strong canonical on parsing JSON files in Python.

However, some of the answers on the Q&A under scrutiny contain references to invalid JSON, which is where the second part of the proposal comes from: to simply remove the references after merging as none of the answers' focus is explicitly on the malformity.

---

Since the proposal requires involvement of a moderator to be enacted upon, a less involved alternative is to close one or the other to serve as a signpost and clean out the references to invalid JSON.

Comment: If we take this option: I volunteer to lead the effort to make a new canonical for JSON syntax issues. Originally I thought that the current question would actually work better as the canonical, but I've changed my mind. "Reading JSON from a file?" has a well written opening question already, and it also does a better job covering the issue of `.load` versus `.loads`. After the appropriate editing, it would probably be simpler and more to the point. There's also something to be said for putting the whole mess behind us: "Reading JSON from a file?" was always substantively the same question.

Comment: What would be the benefit of this merge over simply locking it closed? The merge is a lot of work for arguably poorly fitting answers...

Comment: Both questions properly explain how to parse JSON, and have excellent answers, modulo addressing JSON invalidities that may or may not actually have been present in their OPs' actual data. If we lock or delete this one, the same logic applies to the other one, and then we have no canonical for an extremely important topic. Most of the answers on both questions do not directly reference OP's example data.

Comment: Look at it this way: in the alternate universe where OP had discovered the typo in the sample JSON (*arguendo* it was also in the actual data, and OP fixed the actual data as a result), and then reposted the question with correct data, would we be having this discussion? Almost every actual answer would work as is for that hypothetical re-asked question; and the ones that wouldn't, would just need a bit edited out. We have editing functionality, an OP who walked away happy, and a core question of immense importance. Why would we give up on that completely?

Comment: Whenever someone asks "why shouldn't you edit the intent of a question?", this answer is the canonical.

Answer (score 5):

I went back and read [the previous Meta discussion on this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381492/what-should-be-done-about-this-immensely-popular-but-terrible-and-misleading-que). At that time, the question was at revision 9, looking like:

---

I have this JSON in a file:

```
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "blabla",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ],
    "masks": [
        "id": "valore"
    ],
    "om_points": "value",
    "parameters": [
        "id": "valore"
    ]
}
```

I wrote this script which prints all of the json text:

```
json_data=open(file_directory).read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
pprint(data)
```

How can I parse the file and extract single values?

---

(I took the liberty of removing some blank lines and converting to code fences, but that's substantially what the text was.

Now, keep in mind that this was already 9 years after the fact (ignoring the revoked revision 10), and that the evidence shows that OP walked away satisfied almost right away. While the English is a bit hard to understand, it comes across to me like OP had previously tested the code with working JSON, but used a non-working tool written in Java to produce an example for the post. At any rate it's clear that OP **was able** to get a result from this code, and not an error message. There is *no way* that anyone could mistake a Python exception traceback for "all of the json text". (Furthermore, the stack trace added later - one produced by the *modern* `json` library on the example input - differs significantly from what OP could possibly have seen; `JSONDecodeError` didn't exist in 2010, except perhaps as part of the third-party `simplejson`.)

If we imagine corrections for the typos in the JSON, then the actual **question being asked** was, very clearly, about how to manipulate the `data` result. Here "single" is evidently meant to mean "individual" or "specific". OP seems not to have understood that using `json.loads` parses the data, in the actual sense of the word; perhaps this was due to an idiosyncratic idea of what the word "parse" should mean.

There's another clue: revision 6 removes the word `only` from the description of the problem ("but it only prints all of the text"). The natural interpretation is that "only" was meant like "merely" or "simply"; i.e., using `pprint` *displays* the result, but the goal is to *use* it.

So, it's not actually that hard to figure out: the fourth complaint is the result of an ESL OP making entirely understandable and actually quite minor word choice errors while trying to express a complex idea; and the second and third complaints are actually more or less spurious - the question **didn't need** an example input in the first place because the question is just about *what to do next*. The first complaint is valid, but the real intent was still missed. The changed title shifted from "how to do this" to "why doesn't my attempt to do this work", which was a step backwards - because it **did** apparently work (despite a broken MRE), and because "this" was a red herring.

Okay, but what kind of "usage" did OP have in mind? Again, consider the actual wording: "extract single values". Making allowances for the strange word choice, I can only understand that to mean, in essence, a question like [How to extract a single value from JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788217/) (which I recently polished up). In a world where we were all really good at these sorts of things, I figure, the question would have been dupe-hammered in 2012.

The top answer got around to that eventually, after figuring out what OP meant - which, presumably, is *why OP was satisfied at the time*, and left a deleted answer (converted to a comment, then deleted again) to say thanks. Thus:

---

With data, you can now also find values like so:

```
data["maps"][0]["id"]
data["masks"]["id"]
data["om_points"]
```

---

So.

**If the goal in general is to make questions into the best possible version of what OP wanted to ask**, then it is absolutely not true that "substantial improvements were made to its content" after the first discussion. That discussion ended up totally misinterpreting the context of the problem. If it wasn't the goal to bless a "how do you read and parse JSON?" canonical, then the correct strategy would have been to fix the JSON in the question (or actually remove it entirely), improve the English further, and remove basically everything from the entire answer section aside from the last paragraph of the accepted answer, i.e. the bit I quoted above. (Or the last paragraph of the second most popular answer, which is effectively identical.) Pretty much everything else is tangential, after all. It comes down to OP's apparent misunderstanding of the word "parse", which drew in people who knew how to do the thing described in the title.

However, there's a nagging voice in the back of my head telling me that *maybe this isn't the best way* to deal with questions that are 12 years old, have thousands of upvotes and millions of views, and were mostly misunderstood and misinterpreted for most of that time.

Answer (score 0):

The question was reopened, apparently in response to this post... and then closed again mere hours later. This is the **fifth** time it has been closed. I don't know if that is a Stack Overflow record, but it certainly seems like an exceptional case. Clearly there is some controversy here.

I have noticed with new questions that it happens **all the time** that OP asks "how do I do X?", with code that is the straightforward and normal way to do X, and it's actually a debugging question in disguise. I have also noticed that it's usually very hard for debugging questions to be really good questions.

*That doesn't make all of them useless, however.* It took me, personally, embarrassingly long (without cheating by looking at the answers) to realize what is wrong with the putative JSON data presented. We're all accustomed to JSON data being emitted by standardized tools, but in the real world that doesn't always happen. If you know that some API consumes JSON and you want to test it, you might just hand-craft something simple in a text editor. Plus, there will always be someone in Yet Another Obscure Environment who needs to re-implement those tools

In my view, for *understanding file formats* it's important to have not just the [official documentation](https://json.org/), but "reverse documentation". Just like how API documentation directly explains "X() does Y" but usually you have a long search for "if you want to do Y, use X()", documentation for file formats (and language syntax, for that matter) typically explains what is valid, but leaves what is *invalid* implicit. If there are common *patterns* in how people inadvertently produce something invalid, it's useful to have a guide for *noticing* and *understanding* the problem.

As far as I can tell, we have nothing like a canonical for `JsonDecodeError`s in Python caused by malformed JSON. The most-canonical-looking thing I can find is [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573332) for **empty** data, which is a distinct case with separate causes and a clear "red flag" (the error is reported at `line 1 column 1 (char 0)`). There's also [Handle JSON Decode Error when nothing returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381193/;) but aside from not having a proper MRE (the correct input to show for an MRE, as described, is an empty string, instead of the perfectly valid input shown), it's really just a generic "how do I handle exceptions?" question in disguise. (And again, the fundamental problem appears to be empty data, just that it's being parsed with `simplejson` instead.) There's [Displaying better error message than "No JSON object could be decoded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899506) which is closely related, but also out of date (it does not at all reflect the current reality, and it would be non-trivial to even figure out what versions of Python are affected by the described problem(s)).

---

So, here is my proposal: **Make** this the canonical for questions about malformed JSON.

- Open the question, and make it community wiki. It's clear that the question already is completely transformed from what OP originally typed in, is getting used for a different purpose, and that OP was helped 12 years ago anyway.
- Edit the last line of the question, so that instead of asking about how to use the data, it explicitly asks what the exception means and/or what it is trying to communicate about the data. Alternately, ask a bit more broadly, like (off the top of my head) "what are some common errors in JSON syntax and how can I recognize them?".
- Remove or migrate answers that are *purely* about how to read JSON in Python. They belong at [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/).
- The existing title **is probably fine** for such a topic, although we might expand it a bit to advertise the purpose.
- Conversely: [Reading JSON from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/) is already used as a canonical for the specific question about how to do the reading, but it inappropriately contains a follow-on about invalid JSON syntax (OP shows an example that lacks enclosing `{}`, and an error message of the right sort for that problem, but the wrong details). The follow-on should be edited out of the OP, and content addressing it should be moved to the new "malformed JSON" canonical; and the example JSON in the question should be edited to be valid.
- The new canonical would then also be able to act as a signpost for some other specific issues. For example, "extra data" on line 1 suggests missing enclosing `{}`, but "extra data" on a subsequent line (especially line 2) is more likely because the file is actually in the related JSONL format.

Comment: On second thought, maybe the current question title sounds too much like a rant.

Comment: "*This is the fifth time it has been closed. I don't know if that is a Stack Overflow record, but it certainly seems like an exceptional case*" [SEDE query ranking questions by their number of closures](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1612205/posts-with-most-closures) - 1st place is a question with 16 closures; 2nd place - a question with 10 closures; 3rd place a question with 7 closures; 4th place - several questions with six closures; 5th place several questions with 5 closures. So it's in the top 5, along with another 21 questions. I'd class it as exceptional.

Comment: Why does this need to be _open_? The only reason to keep it _open_ is if you'd want to allow for new answers, which is pretty pointless here, as the only answer you need is _"Fix yer JSON"_. There's nothing useful that the closure prevents / blocks, and it _does_ block the creation of redundant answers.

Comment: In other words: You provided enough reasons to not delete this Q/A, but none that require it to stay opened.

Comment: @Cerbrus Questions being open is the default state on Stack Overflow, for better or worse, and nearly all canonicals are (although many are protected), even though they realistically are already thoroughly answered. That said: if the question were open and fixed per my proposal, I specifically could add, e.g., an answer pointing out that there is a separate JSONL format that can be detected by a characteristic version of `JsonDecodeError`, and offer a link to the canonical for how to parse that.

Comment: That's still not a reason that this one _should_ be opened. The `JSONL` format isn't relevant to this question at all.

Comment: (please see edit)

Comment: @Cerbrus Any question judged to be suitable for the site should remain open. New answers may arise as the technology evolves. Closure does not mean "no new answers." It means something is wrong with the question. Your argument completely misses the point of closure.

Comment: This is a typo question. We need a good argument why it should stay open, __despite__ it being a typo. We don't need to justify the closure any further.

Comment: It was **turned into** a typo question. The initial round of answers did not address any typo, and OP promptly indicated that the problem was solved. The initial question did not complain of any error, and implied that the code successfully output something. OP either didn't understand that the (improperly represented in the post, but valid locally) data was already "parsed", or didn't understand how to work with it so as to "extract single values". I am quoting directly from revision 1 here.

Comment: The way I see it, we have 2 options: 1: Completely rewrite the question back into the original one. 2: Keel the question as is, and close it, as it is _now_ a typo question. Either way, keeping it open in the current state is _not_ an option.

Comment: (I was mistaken: the original answers did mention the typo, but it comes across like they were edited after some now-missing comment exchange where OP tried to clarify.)

Answer (score 0):

### 2023 update

I came back to this today because I stumbled upon a much better canonical. The previously proposed canonical [Reading JSON from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126) is not good enough, because the example data was invalid, taking focus away from the parsing question. However, earlier today I [asked a different question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422738) that happened to touch on the topic of JSON parsing, and received an excellent canonical suggestion (credit to Abdul Aziz Barkat) from the comments: [How can I parse and use JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011).

This question was already properly focused: it showed a clear and understandable example input **that is actually valid JSON**, and **did not** distract from the question by showing non-working example code or an error message - it only suggested "I think I need to use ; but how?".

For years, the question received only minor copy-editing. I gave it a complete overhaul by:

- asking a question more explicitly and removing noise
- using clearer grammar
- rearranging so that there is an explicit question about the general case, followed by an example with a restatement of the question in that specific context
- [Adding see-also links in smaller text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863/editing-old-questions-to-add-links-to-similar-ones/419864#419864) to highlight one special case of using the data and interpreting it in a specific way (Pandas) as well as several cases of "JSON lookalike" data not properly addressed by the question. The first link is intended more for Pandas users who may have assumed they need to create a `Dataframe` manually from the parsed data; the others are intended more for duplicate closers, to help find canonicals for related problems.

I then added my own comprehensive answer to the new canonical, and redirected the old proposal there. **Please use this question going forward** to close simple questions about reading and parsing JSON.

Based on the discussion in the other Meta question, I agree that a canonical like this is also appropriate to close typical questions about "embedded" JSON (since there is **nothing special** about it; the technique is to simply take the string from the parsed JSON that represents the embedded JSON, and parse it again). I made sure that my answer to the canonical explicitly addresses this topic.

We still seem to be missing one or more canonicals to explain how to diagnose common problems with JSON - i.e., data in a similar non-JSON format, or corrupted data (or data written by hand erroneously, or output from a buggy tool).